# intelliJ plugin installation path

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, path

I have installed `visualvm` plugin in from the dedicated `intelliJ` panel. I am now the plugin path. I can't find it, I tried :  `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX` but I only get the two files `availables.xml extensions.xml`. I suppose the path I am asked is the jar file of the installed plugin, but I don't know where it is stored. Could someone help ?

Comment: The plugins folder is located in the `[Install Dir]/JetBrains/IntelliJ Ideaxxx/plugins` was there an error during the plugin installation ?

Comment: @KennethClark sorry if it is a stupid question, but where is the JetBrains directory ? the doc indicates `~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdeaXX` but I find nothing (as indicated here `https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs`)

Comment: Are you using Linux ?

Comment: @KennethClark no I am using `OSX`

Comment: I have not actually installed IntelliJ on OSX but im assuming it will be in the following path `/opt/local/Library/`

Answer (score 3):

Mac

`/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins`

Answer (score 1):

[Location of the IDE files depends on the operating system, product and version.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Windows:
Plugins (idea.plugins.path):
C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins

macOS:
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/Library/Application

Linux:
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JetBrains documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) it locates here for IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2:

Windows:

```
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): %APPDATA%\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\plugins
```

macOS:

```
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/plugins
```

Linux:

```
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): ~/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2
```

Take into account on mac I could find it via terminal.